# how to convert a model object to an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

i have the following query that gets data regarding a vessel as follows

```
     public async Task<ExcelListModel>HandleAsync(VesselCrewQuery query)
     {  
       var test= await _queryDispatcher.DispatchAsync<FetchByIdQuery, VesselModel>(new FetchByIdQuery() { Id=query.vesselId});
       eModel = await generateExcel(test, lineItems,hint);
     }
```

i want to pass the above test variable into generateExcel file.

```
 public async Task<ExcelListModel> generateExcel(dynamic header,dynamic lines, string[][] fieldHints = null)
        {

            var HeaderlistModContent = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            // when i get here (IEnumerable) header; it throws an error 
            var Headerlist =(IEnumerable) header;
            foreach (var item in Headerlist)
            {
                var HeaderModContent = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                var HeaderProperty = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (var prop in HeaderProperty)
                {
                    var name = prop.Name.ToString();
                    var value = GetPropertyValue(item, name).ToString();
                    HeaderModContent.Add(name, value);
                }
                HeaderlistModContent.Add(HeaderModContent);
            }
}


public static object GetPropertyValue(object source, string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            return property.GetValue(source, null);
        }
```

i want to pass the test variable so that i can extract the headings as above.But i get the following error `**Unable to cast object of type 'VesselModel' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.**`

i tried to change it as follows

```
var test= await _queryDispatcher.DispatchAsync<FetchByIdQuery,List< VesselModel>>(new FetchByIdQuery() { Id=query.vesselId});
```

but i still get the same error

Comment: Seems to me we miss some information to get what this code is doing. What is `GetPropertyValue` ? also, what's `ExcelListModel`? On which line is the error?

Comment: I have updated the getpropertyvalue, it breaks on this line  var Headerlist =(IEnumerable) header; it doesnt go any further

Comment: And? Does VesselModel implement IEnumerable? We don't now anything about those classes. So we can just throw the stuff the runtime throws at you also.

Comment: Why are those parameters of generateExcel dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

By signature the return type of the method `DispatchAsync` is `VeselModel`:

```
 var test= await _queryDispatcher.DispatchAsync<FetchByIdQuery, VesselModel>(new FetchByIdQuery() { Id=query.vesselId});
```

It hints that `VesselModel` could be a single instance (not a collection). It's even indicated by `FetchByIdQuery`; usually, you should get a single item by Id. Even error message hints that it's not a collection.

So, you are passing a single instance to `generateExcel` as the parameter `dynamic header`. And a single instance can't be cast to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: perfectly possible that the `SomeFunction<T1, T2>` is set to return an `IEnumerable<T2>`. We need to see the return type of `DispatchAsync`

Comment: Even changing signature to DispatchAsync<FetchByIdQuery,List<VesselModel>> I doubt that it's returning list of `VesselModel`. Especially taking into account that error message is pretty explicit regarding that. It's not reading that List<VesselModel> can't be cast to IEnumerable.